# HQL SQL GrammarException : Could not extract ResultSet from ManyToMany Field Query

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, hql

I am stuck with the following exception:

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet.

I have the following class `Organisation`. Take a look at my `@ManyToMany` attributes `sousTraitants` and `donneurDOrdre`.

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "t_organisation" , indexes = {
} )
public class Organisation implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column( name = "N_ID" )
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    protected Long id;

    @Basic
    @Column( name = "C_RAISONSOCIALE", nullable = false )
    private String raisonSociale;

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, mappedBy = "organisation"  )
    private Set<Individu> personnels;
    
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    @JoinTable(
        name = "SousTraitant_Organisation", 
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "N_DONNEURDORDRE_ORGID") }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "N_SOUSTRAITANT_ORGID") }
        )
    private Set<Organisation> sousTraitants = new HashSet<>();
    
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sousTraitants")
    private Set<Organisation> donneurDOrdre = new HashSet<>();
```

I tried the following query to retrieve a list of `Organisation`:

```
List<Organisation> result = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession()
.createQuery( "SELECT o FROM " + Organisation.class.getName() + " o JOIN o.sousTraitants WHERE o.donneurDOrdre = :idDonneurDOrdre", Organisation.class )
.setParameter( "idDonneurDOrdre", idDonneurDOrdre )
.getResultList();
```

But I still have the same exception message, and I'm not whether it's my `@ManyToMany` annotation which is wrong or my query.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds that I found the answer :

```
return HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery( "SELECT o FROM " + Organisation.class.getName() + " o JOIN o.sousTraitants s WHERE s.id = :idDonneurDOrdre", Organisation.class ).setParameter( "idDonneurDOrdre", idDonneurDOrdre ).getResultList();
```